# Find the chance of being selected (probability)

Tags: probability

First of all, I'm sorry if title was not clear, I thought about it for 5 minutes and I couldn't make it better. (English is not my first language)

Ok, now the task is the following.
In one class, there are 20 girls and 12 boys. On a revision, the teacher choose with the same probability for each student, one by one, three students. What is the probability the chosen student to be: a) male, b)female if the teacher has chosen 2 girls firstly?

Comment: for a, is it all males?  You said we're choosing 3 students but in a) you say the probability of the chosen student is male.  Do you mean all males?  or the probability of the first student picked is male?

Comment: The first 2 chosen are girls.

Comment: your sample space is 32; 20 girls + 12 boys.  for b, if you've already chosen two girls, then your remaining sample space is 30: 18 girls + 12 boys.  Does this help?

Comment: So, 30:30=1? Sorry, I don't get you, but I got the task done already. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the given circumstances, there are 18 girsl and 12 boys left as the third choice is made. Thus the probabilities are $\frac{12}{12+18}=\frac25$ and $\frac35$, respectively.

Comment: Wow. That simple? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of choosing two girls first = $\frac{20}{32}\frac{19}{31}$.  The remaining sample space for the third choice is 30.  you should be able to calculate the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the two girls are chosen firstly by the task itself, I don't have to calculate that, although I've done the rest. :)

Comment: It was more of a formality doing the probability of the two girls first.